# Passing an array created in function to other functions

Tags: c++

I'm beginning my programming adventure in C++. I want to write a small program, which has to create an array in function create (size has to be defined in create function) and transfer them to function display which will print entered values.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *create(int & n);
void display(int * arr, int n);

int main()
{
    int n;
    int * arr = create(n);
    display(arr, n);


    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}

int *create(int & n) {
    cout << "How many elements? ";
    cin >> n;
    int * arr = new int[n];
    int element;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << endl << "Enter " << i << " array element: ";
        cin >> element;
        arr[i] = element;
    }

    return arr;
}

void display(int * arr, int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << endl << i << " element: " << arr[i];
    }
}
```

I'm looking for every criticism, optimization suggest and everything which will help me be a better programmer and not to learn bad habits from the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the usual criticisms:

- Don't use `using namespace std;`
- Don't use raw `new` and `delete`
- Include the headers your code uses (e.g. `<iostream>`)
- Prefer prefix `++i` over postfix `i++` as a general habit
- Prefer to omit the implied `return 0;` from `main` (unless you're trying to emphasize that the return value is different via different codepaths, which doesn't apply in this case)

Then, the point specific to your API design:

- Your function `create` has two outputs: the *pointer to a new array* and the *size of the new array*, `n`. The former is returned as the return value; the latter is passed in by reference (the *out-parameter* pattern). Instead of returning these two pieces of information by two different routes, you should unify them: Either pass in *two* out-parameters (yuck!) or pass out *two* values by return.

Taking the latter approach (two values by return) and applying all our rules *except* "no raw `new` and `delete`", we end up with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

std::pair<int *, int> create() {
    int n;
    std::cout << "How many elements? ";
    std::cin >> n;
    int *arr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int element;
        std::cout << std::endl << "Enter " << i << " array element: ";
        std::cin >> element;
        arr[i] = element;
    }
    return {arr, n};
}

void display(int *arr, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << std::endl << i << " element: " << arr[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    auto [arr, n] = create(n);
    display(arr, n);
    delete [] arr;
}
```

The JavaScript-looking `[arr, n]` is C++17 syntax, but don't worry, we're about to get rid of it in our next refactor.

Applying "no raw `new` and `delete`" allows us to simplify much further:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> create() {
    int n;
    std::cout << "How many elements? ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int element;
        std::cout << std::endl << "Enter " << i << " array element: ";
        std::cin >> element;
        result.push_back(element);
    }
    return result;
}

void display(const std::vector<int>& vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < int(vec.size()); ++i) {
        std::cout << std::endl << i << " element: " << vec[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    auto vec = create(n);
    display(vec);
}
```

The last thing I'd consider doing is *eliminating mutation* from the code. You've got these variables `int n` and `int element` that aren't initialized, and then you use `std::cin >> ...` to mutate their values. It might be more straightforward to write an "int-getting function" and use it consistently. Plus, this gives us a place to hang the missing `std::flush`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
T input(const char *prompt) {
    T result;
    // Print out everything in `prompt` (C++17 syntax)
    std::cout << prompt << " " << std::flush;
    std::cin >> result;  // Should we add some error-checking?
                 // What if the user types "hello world" here?
    return result;
}

std::vector<int> create() {
    std::vector<int> result;
    int n = input<int>("How many elements?");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        result.push_back(input<int>("Enter the next array element:"));
    }
    return result;
}

void display(const std::vector<int>& vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < int(vec.size()); ++i) {
        std::cout << std::endl << i << " element: " << vec[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    display(create(n));
}
```

Notice that I changed your prompt from `"Enter the 42 array element:"` to simply `"Enter the next array element:"`. This was because I didn't want to bother explaining how to write a variadic-template version of `input` that would accept `input<int>("Enter the ", i, " array element:")`. It's possible — even trivial, in C++17 where we can write `(std::cout << ... << prompt_pieces) << " " << std::flush` — but I want to keep the simple code simple.

Now we've localized all the icky "state mutation" into the innards of `input<int>`; we don't have to think about mutation while we're reading `create`.

Comment: I guess I’m not the only one abusing templates :) also, did you want to return T from input?

Comment: Good call! Fixed. (And yeah, I had it as a non-template at first, but then figured the template version wouldn't be *too* complicated. As indicated, I resisted the urge to make it take anything more complicated than `const char *`.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone Nice work :) Now i'll study your improvements for my code, it really looks so much better. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: You can emphasise the non-mutating nature in `create()` by writing `const int n = input...` (though I'd recommend a `std::size_t` for the size) - is it also worth mentioning `std::vector::reserve()` once the size is known?